# SQL Query to Display All Columns in SSRS Report for Comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have been working this through a variety of venues and I thought I had it resolved with a previous question, and further searches have not yet yielded fruit.

Quick and Dirty:  I have a set of values in a single table within SQL 2012 that I want to all the values to appear in a column on the left side of the screen. I then want a variable, which can have multiple values, to run and display granted if there is a match with the column on the left.  I cannot get my query in SQL to work correctly, but this will eventually be displayed in a SSRS report.

The @GroupName is a Parameter within the SSRS report pulled dynamically from the available group names.  The data needed for the comparison is stored in three different tables and I don't have the ability to modify the database as it is a COTS product.

Priv_Table contains the privileges that can be assigned (log in, control a, etc.) and their correlating id #
Info_Table contains the names of the groups and the group id #
Prof_info_Table contains the group id # matched to the individual Priv id # information.  In the below example Group 1's ID would be listed three times, each time associated to a unique Priv id #.  (ex. 1-1, 1-2, 1-4)

### Example:

```
           Group 1  Group 2   Group 3   Group 4
Log In         X       X          X        X
Control A      X                  X 
Control B                         X 
Control C      X                  X 
Delete A                                   X
Delete B                
Delete C                                   X
```

---

In the above example, my existing query if I selected Group 1 as the group to query would only return Log In, Control A, and Control C on the left.  If I ran it with Group 1 & Group 3 then Control B would show up with a blank in the Group 1 Column as expected.  However I want all the options to show up regardless of which Group is selected to query against.

I see two ways forward, figure out a way to pull all the data (maybe in a subquery) to always populate one column and then do a case statement against the subquery to display the desired result or fix the existing query.

Here is what I have so far and the problem with each of them:

```
    SELECT Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc, Info_Table.ProfileName, CASE WHEN
    Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc LIKE '%' THEN 'Granted' END AS PermissionHeld
    FROM Priv_Table LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Prof_Info_Table ON Priv_Table.PrivilegeID = Prof_Info_Table.PrivilegeID INNER JOIN
    Info_Table ON Prof_Info_Table.ProfileID = Info_Table.ProfileID
    WHERE (Info_Table.ProfileName IN (@GroupName))
    ORDER BY Priv_Table.PrivilegeID
```

This is the query I currently have that is working as described in the example above.  I get the same behavior within SQL and SSRS, and I have tried all different Joins and removing the case statement and it still occurs.

If I run this query then I get all the possible values for the permissions:

```
      SELECT Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc
      FROM Priv_Table
```

I've tried including that in SSRS as a subreport within SSRS but then I cannot get the matching to work at all with that configuration.

```
    SELECT Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc, Info_Table.ProfileName, CASE WHEN Exists
    (SELECT Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc, Info_Table.ProfileName FROM Priv_Table Left Outer Join
    Prof_Info_Table ON Priv_Table.PrivilegeID = Prof_Info_Table.PrivilegeID INNER JOIN
    Info_Table ON Prof_Info_Table.ProfileID = Info_Table.ProfileID WHERE
    Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc like '%' ) THEN 'Granted' ELSE NULL END AS 'PermissionHeld'
    From Priv_Table, Info_Table
    WHERE (Info_Table.ProfileName IN (@GroupName))
```

This query returns all the values on the left most column, however shows granted (or an X for the example) for all permissions including those that the group does not have access to.  So Group 1 would have X's in all rows using the example from above even though it should only have log in, control a, and control C.

Comment: A couple of questions for you. The first query is dropping the blank rows right? I believe I understand the schema...you are trying to get the final output to look like your table? Assuming yes here, is the number of columns constant?

Comment: Correct, the first query is dropping all the rows that the group does not have. So group 1 only would return log in, control a, and control c as the only rows on the left side.  If you ran the query with all the groups selected, then all the columns on the left would show up except for Delete B.  The groups that didn't have that access would show blanks where they didn't have permissions, but the report would never show Delete B.  

The number of rows will be constant, but not the number of columns.  The number of columns depends on how many groups are selected within the report.

Comment: I guess what I meant to ask is - is the number of groups fairly small and static? Or are there hundreds of groups and therefore potentially hundreds of columns?

Comment: They vary based on site, but I think the most is probably around 70, and that would be only if they selected all the groups to run at once.

Comment: I think this is going to be hard to manage. Left joining on to your privilege table is easy enough (see Wes H's answer). Getting the data to fit horizontally is going to be more of a challenge. Is it easier to pivot and put the privileges on top and the groups down the side or are there lots of privileges too? There may be away to set up horizontal grouping but I haven't played with it. What will work is to create 70 anonymous columns e.g. Val1, Val2... and 70 more header name columns (ColHead1, ColHead2, etc...) populate them appropriately using the PIVOT function then hide the empty columns.

Comment: I'm not worried about the data fitting horizontally, they can run reports with fewer profiles if they need to print.  Unfortunately, there are hundreds of permissions.  Wes H's solution is working great with the exception of a blank column before the GroupNames start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you have a Left Join followed by an Inner Join.  The inner join effectively converts the Left Join to an Inner Join as well.

That may be part of your problem, but it is hard to tell without sample data.

Another option, create a distinct list of your privileges and then left join to your results.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  DISTINCT Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc,
    FROM  Priv_Table
) AS PT
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc,
        Info_Table.ProfileName,
        PermissionHeld = CASE
                           WHEN Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc LIKE '%' THEN 'Granted'    
                         END
    FROM  Priv_Table
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Prof_Info_Table
                  ON Priv_Table.PrivilegeID = Prof_Info_Table.PrivilegeID
    INNER JOIN Info_Table
             ON Prof_Info_Table.ProfileID = Info_Table.ProfileID
    WHERE (Info_Table.ProfileName IN ( @GroupName ))
) AS Profiles
ON PT.PrivilegeDesc = Profiles.PrivilegeDesc
```

Comment: That works very well.  For some reason I have a blank first column before the GroupNames begin.  I had tried doing multiple types of joins without success.

Comment: I assume that you have a blank description in your Priv_Table.PrivilegeDesc field.  You can try filtering that out in the distinct select, but make sure you review how that affects the other results.  If a Profile does not have a privilege, the intersection should be null, not blank.

Comment: As I've run this one down further, the first column is not always blank.  It depends on which groups are selected.  So, I am just going to live with it because I haven't seen any blank descriptions anywhere.  Thank you for all your help.